# What is the recommended mobile apps that assist in meditation?

Tags: meditation, meditation-practicalities

I have been meditating for a few years now. I love the ones that deal with breathe control. I have use Headspace, calm, and balanced. All help a little but I have done trials of all three and don’t know which is better. Please help

Comment: This is a type of question that would be considered off-topic on other SE sites -- because it's a "product recommendation?" question. It doesn't even specify what you mean by "better" i.e. what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

The Buddha provided instructions on meditation. Those instructions are the original "app". You can use your phone to read such instruction:

> [DN22:1.7](https://suttacentral.net/dn22/en/sujato#dn22:1.7): “Mendicants, the four kinds of mindfulness meditation are the path to convergence. They are in order to purify sentient beings, to get past sorrow and crying, to make an end of pain and sadness, to discover the system, and to realize extinguishment.

On your phone, you can also *listen* to the same thing:

> https://www.sc-voice.net/#/sutta/dn22/en/sujato

Listening is quite important. All meditation apps focus on listening. Why is that?

The suttas were originally spoken and heard as is, in the moment. In this age of fast looking and grabbing, the art of listening mindfully has sadly slipped into disuse. You may notice that modern meditation apps have an emphasis on sound. Listening mindfully is quite important. The ears must hear what happens in the moment. Eyes tend to grab what glitters. So we tend to use our phones as eyes onto the world, grabbing whatever catches our fancy, leaving us unsatisfied. Meditation apps turn away from the grasping of sight and allow you to explore listening. And if you're going to explore listening, well, try listening to Buddhist suttas, especially the ones on meditation itself.

> [MN143:5.1](https://suttacentral.net/mn143/en/sujato#mn143:5.1): “That’s why, householder, you should train like this:
> [MN143:5.2](https://suttacentral.net/mn143/en/sujato#mn143:5.2): ‘I shall not grasp the eye, and there shall be no consciousness of mine dependent on the eye.’